# Syntax error with creating a stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

Currently, I am working on an inventory system that will allow the client to customize their own SQL Server tables.

[image: The C# WPF GUI <<< PICTURE]

The user will name their column then specify the data type they would like to use. After they are satisfied with their table they click on the submit table button to create their table. C# then will create a unique table for the user by running a SQL Server stored procedure.

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Constants.conn);
connection.Open();

string query = "EXEC CreateTable @TableName='"+ UserAccountInfo.Username + "InventoryTable'";

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
command.ExecuteReader();
```

Then using a foreach loop, iterating through each column added (class UserTable is my custom WPF UserControl) by looking at the Stack panel "StackTable" Children, and assigning the properties of the Usertable "Name" and "DataType" to the List of String Arrays. Then I iterate throughout the list and execute the second stored procedure that alters the table previously created.

I believe all of this to work!! My question and problem lies in my stored procedure.

```
List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();

foreach (UserTable ut in StackTable.Children)
{
    string dataType = "";

    switch (ut.DataType.Text)
    {
        case "Text": dataType = "Varchar(100)"; break;
        case "Number": dataType = "INT"; break;
        case "Boolean": dataType = "Varchar(5)"; break;
    }

    string[] vs = {"[" + ut.Name.Text + "]", dataType};
    list.Add(vs);
}

foreach (string[] s in list)
{
    string query2 = "EXEC SelectAllCustomers @Name = '" + s[0] + "', @DataType = '" + s[1] + "';";

    SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    command2.ExecuteReader();
}
```

My DATABASE Schema consists of the base database called `InventoryDatabase`, inside a table called `LoginInfo` where I store the user's information, and the rest of the tables are going to be the tables we are creating above. PROBLEM IS, my stored procedures are throwing syntax errors.

[image: SQL Server Management Studio Query of stored procedure <<< PICTURE]

Comment: You can't say `ALTER TABLE @TableName` - please read up on dynamic SQL _and_ SQL injection.

Comment: It's `Stored` (not `Storage`).

Comment: Variables can't be used to replace the names of objects; certainly not without dynamic SQL anyway. But I strongly suggest you don't go down this path either as it is clear you are oblivious to the extremely large dangers of SQL Injection. What is your *real* goal here?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use dynamic SQL.  Here's an example to get you started:

```
create or alter procedure CreateTable @TableName varchar(100)
as
begin
     declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 
     concat('create table ',quotename(@TableName),' AccountId int primary key identity(1,1)');
     exec (@sql);
end
```

Note that the name is passed through the `quotename` function to protect against SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: prepare the SQL script as a string which can able to Create or alter the table in your C# code and then execute prepared string using `ExecuteNonQuery` method.

Option 2: by using dynamic SQL concept, prepare the create/alter table script with in a stored procedure and then execute